# Prepros: Error minifying JS

Tags: javascript, compilation, prepros

I have a file `script/qArray/questions.js` and here's the thing: it won't minify. This is all the code I have in it:

```
var QuizCard = function (question, options, answer, explanation) {

}
```

And *voila* comes out the error.

[image: The error.]
`top_retain.indexOf() is not a function.` That's what it said.

What's going on?

Edit: Here's something, this code worked perfectly well yesterday. Today, it seemed to update (from 6.0.13 to 6.0.14) and doesn't work anymore. Changelog:
`Fixed an error while minifying some js files`

Answer (score 0):

It says unknown to process file, check if the file path is correct then check by determining if the code is in error then -> go step by step also knowing which minifying code base you're using can help :),

sorry if this seems a little redundant. :D but i ran your code another online minifier and it worked fine :)

Comment: Hmm... It seems that the code works well if I turn off UglifyJS. But that's the whole point here, I want to minify my code.

Comment: https://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/
tried it on there hmm what version of uglify js are you running on npm, im assuming

Comment: I'm using Prepros. This thing: prepros.io/download

Comment: will give a try in the program

Comment: i just installed the program ran a build and the dist build did correctly minify the package i dont know how this program checks its package dependencies globally i recommend updating or re downloading the application. :) or you can install npm and run uglify on your own hehe